# Formatting textbox.text specific format like : ##.###.###/####-##

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox, format

I need a format like this for 14 chars:

> 10.257.938/0001.45

But when I execute this code, I get

> ### .###.###/####-

on my `txtcnpj.text`.

I really don't like to use maskedbox.
Here's my code (on lost focus.):

```
Private Sub txtcnpj_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtcnpj.LostFocus

        If Len(txtcnpj.Text) > 0 Then

            Select Case Len(txtcnpj.Text)

                Case Is = 11
                    txtcnpj.Text = Format(txtcnpj.Text, "###.###.###-##")

                Case Is = 14
                    txtcnpj.Text = Format(txtcnpj.Text, "##.###.###/####-##")
                    
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

[OR WHEN I USED ##.###.###/####-##](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MmJE.png)
RETURN

SOLVED BY Andrew Morton,
TY ANDREW . UHUL .

In my case solution is:

```
Private Sub txtcnpj_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtcnpj.LostFocus

    If Len(txtcnpj.Text) > 0 Then

        Select Case Len(txtcnpj.Text)

                      Case Is = 14
                Dim A As String
                A = txtcnpj.Text.Replace("."c, "").Replace("/"c, "")
                txtcnpj.Text = String.Concat(A.Substring(0, 2), ".", A.Substring(2, 3), ".", A.Substring(5, 3), "/", A.Substring(8, 4), "-", A.Substring(12, 2))

        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `#`... instead of `@`...

Comment: same error look image : https://i.imgur.com/KzZKQuV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting like that is for numbers, not strings.

It will be simplest to write your own methods, for example:

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Function FormatWithSlash(s As String) As String
        s = s.Replace("."c, "").Replace("/"c, "")
        Return String.Concat(s.Substring(0, 2), ".", s.Substring(2, 3), ".", s.Substring(5, 3), "/", s.Substring(8, 4), ".", s.Substring(12, 2))
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(FormatWithSlash("12345678901234"))
        Console.WriteLine(FormatWithSlash("10.257.938/0001.45"))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

outputs:

> 12.345.678/9012.34
>   10.257.938/0001.45

Comment: erro, https://i.imgur.com/ervYXtD.png because return string not value.
need convert.

have some ideia ?

Comment: You want a Sub, not a Function, and you need to use `yourControl.Text = String.Concat(......)`.

Comment: Uow man you the best , ty for solution .
+ rep .

Works like a baby on heaven.

https://i.imgur.com/bj7JS9q.png

Comment: I dont have 15 points to like up your REP , but you solved my case .
ty.

Comment: I really thank you, as I have not had enough knowledge to solve this, now evaluating the code you wrote I have the knowledge to format any value; Thank you ! Can you tell me a good enough place for further study as in this case where you learned for example? Or have you learned over time ...

Comment: @Perroni I mostly picked things up over time. If you like video tutorials, the ones by Bob Tabor on MSDN seem good to me: [Visual Basic Fundamentals for Absolute Beginners](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Basic-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners/01).